# Storing images in Javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, html, image

So I'm having trouble figuring out if there is a way to store local images saved on my computer and put them into variables so that way a certain picture will display when it's called. I've been looking everywhere and I keep finding variations of this answer or things that are more than what I'm looking for.
I know that you have to bring them into the `body` tag first, you can't just throw them into the variable beforehand. I don't want them being displayed right off the bat though, just when referenced as a variable.

```
<img src="project1pics/groot.jpg" id="groot">
<img src="project1pics/starlord.jpg" id="starLord">
<img src="project1pics/rocket.jpg" id="rocket">
<img src="project1pics/gamora.jpg" id="gamora">
<img src="project1pics/drax.jpg" id="drax">
```

Then inside the script tags I tried using `document.getElementById` for each image ID I set as a way to put them into the variables.

```
var groot = document.getElementById("groot")
var starLord = document.getElementById("starLord")
var rocket = document.getElementById("rocket")
var gamora = document.getElementById("gamora")
var drax = document.getElementById("drax")
```

I've tried several different things, but I've had no luck with anything I've done.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. If your are loading images from an external resource, as you do in your code, then why "store" them inside a variable? You will already have them in the local browser cache, so available at an instant. What often is done though is to have a reference, a selector that _points to_ an element holding such an image or that is able to create an element referencing such an image.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... Why don't you simply hide and show these images?

Comment: Lots of ways to store them without having to put them in the page html. Question is really far too broad

Comment: I'm trying to make a "Buzzfeed" personality quiz where depending on the answers the user selects they get a different result. There are five different results they can get, each one would display it's own picture, hence why I don't want them all being displayed at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible to hide all the images at first with CSS, then depending on the user's score, display the image that corresponds to their score?

Comment: You should remove your last edit and publish it as another question. You can't use a single Q&A to ask questions as you find issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can create image elements using vanilla JavaScript and instantiate them prior to adding them to the document:

```
var img1 = document.createElement("img");
img1.src = "http://path/to/image";
```

...and append one using `appendChild`:

```
document.body.appendChild(img1);
document.querySelector(".some-class").appendChild(img1);
document.getElementById("someId").appendChild(img1);
```

#### Taken from some comment added to the question by the OP:

> Is it possible to hide all the images at first with CSS, then
>   depending on the user's score, display the image that corresponds to
>   their score?

You can also do that easily:

```
<img id="score1" class="hidden">
<img id="score2" class="hidden">
<img id="score3" class="hidden">

.hidden { display: none; }

var score2Element = document.getElementById("score2");
score2Element.classList.remove("hidden");
```

Comment: Ok awesome the appendChild worked the way I wanted it to. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript way to call images stored in vars that does not needs the html img tag:

```js
var aaa = "http://i.imgur.com/ZLAfFHN.jpg";
var bbb = "http://i.imgur.com/23lydbM.jpg";

function createimg(key,sizeA,sizeB) {
var theimage = document.createElement("img");
theimage.setAttribute('src', key);
theimage.setAttribute('alt', 'image');
theimage.height = sizeA;
theimage.width = sizeB;
document.body.appendChild(theimage);  
}
```

```css
img {
 vertical-align:top; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="createimg(aaa,80,80)">Create image A</button>
<button onclick="createimg(bbb,60,60)">Create image B</button>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my image not loading so I was trying different way of storing an image into a variable and found a very very simple solution.

In the path, you need to put two backslashes for every folder because the program interprets one backslash differently.

So you should write it like this.

image.src = "C:\\Users\\tyler\\Desktop\\Javascript Crash Course\\Cat.jpg"